# Could someone help me with parsing this JSON file?

Tags: android, json, parsing, textview

I have this JSON file:

```
 {
    "ics_desire":{
    "version":"Beta 0.1.1",
    "description":"description here",
    "build-fingerprint":"fingerprint"
 }
```

Now I want to put the `version` part in a txtVersion textview and the `description` part in the txtDescription textview.

Would someone help me?

Comment: You should probably paste the contents of the JSON file if you want someone to be able to help you...

Comment: First of all, make sure your JSON is valid. Right now, it's not. It has 2 opening brackets, and one closing bracket.  Also, what have you tried so far? This amount of JSON data is not complex, so any number of tutorials will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So first off to state what was said above you JSON code is incorrectly formatted. You can validate you have correctly formated JSON code by going to http://json.parser.online.fr/. 
Your correct JSON would be as follows (you were missing a closing })

```
{
"ics_desire": {
    "version": "Beta 0.1.1",
    "description": "description here",
    "build-fingerprint": "fingerprint"
}
}
```

Next, here is an example of a working JSON code that I have used to test with in the past.

```
{
"HealthySubstituteData": [
    {
        "Assoc_ID": "1",
        "uFood": "White Flour",
        "hFood": "Wheat Flour",
        "Category": "Baking",
        "Description": "You can substitute blah blah blah...",
        "Count": "5",
        "submittedBy": "Administrator"
    }
]
}
```

And here is the code I use to get that data.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://your.url.com/whaterver");

    try
    {
        JSONArray  healthySubstituteData = json.getJSONArray("HealthySubstituteData");



        for(int i=0;i<healthySubstituteData.length();i++)
        {                       
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = healthySubstituteData.getJSONObject(i);



            map.put("Assoc_ID", (String) e.get("Assoc_ID"));
            map.put("uFood", (String) e.get("uFood"));
            map.put("hFood", (String) e.get("hFood"));
            map.put("category", (String) e.get("Category"));
            map.put("description", (String) e.get("Description"));
            map.put("count", (String) e.get("Count"));
            map.put("submittedBy", (String) e.get("submittedBy"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }
```

So now I end up with an array list of type HashMap and I can do whatever I want with it at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple class like

```
public class Myclass{
String version;
String description;
String build-fingerprint;
};
```

and then use Gson to convert json to your object and vice versa:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Myclass obj = gson.fromJson(json_string, Myclass.class);
```

json_string should contain your jason string.
Now you can get your class objects values using getters.

```
Note: Gson is an external library you need to import, download it from google.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring about the missing brackets in JSON, this code would help you through

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://your.url.com/whaterver"); //the site where you get your JSON
JSONObject daata = json.getJSONObject("ics_desire"); //grabbing the inner object
String version = daata.getString("version");         //grabbing values
String description = daata.getString("description");
txtVersion.setText(version);                         //Hope you have initialized the Views.
txtDescription.setText(description);
```